# Reuse component on same page each with its own state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to reuse same component multiple times under one parent component. All the SortLabels are sharing same state. So when clicked on one element and the state from previous click is being reflected. How do I make them independent components with separate state?

```
class SortLabel extends Component {

constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        order: 'asc',
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

toggle() {
    this.setState({order: this.state.order === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'});
}

render() {
    const {itemProperty, sortingProperty} = this.props;

    return (            
        <TableSortLabel
            key={`Sort ${itemProperty.get('id')}`}
            id={`Sort ${itemProperty.get('id')}`}
            active = {sortingProperty === itemProperty.get('id')}
            onClick = {this.toggle}
            direction={this.state.order}>
            {itemProperty.get('description')}
        </TableSortLabel>             
    )
 }
}
```

**Update**
After testing this, components have separate state. The issue was because of the way I was handling state

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the way you have it set up, your binding the same variables from the parent component to the child component (i.e id). so you just need to separate it somehow: id1, id2, etc... to better answer your question i might like to see the parent component